# Graylog2 Alarms for non admins

Tags: alarms, graylog2

How can unprivileged users subscribe to alarms?

Administrators see the alarm tab on each stream. It lets you subscribe in order to get an email if a message limit per timeframe is hit. For "readers" the tab is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the currently released versions. However, v0.20.0 is released these days (Preview version are already available) that will allow you to do that.

Comment: thank you! its great that you implemented it. will update soon.